# Acumatica Grid Loses rows on refresh

Tags: acumatica

I have the following Data Views in my graph

```
public PXSelectReadonly<Branch> Branch;
public PXSelectReadonly<BAFileUpload, Where<BAFileUpload.branchID, Equal<Current<Branch.branchID>>>> History;
```

When I load the page initially all the data is displayed correctly on the screen, but when I press the refresh button on the browser for some strange reason the grid is not populated and when the Row Selected Event fires the row in the event arguments is set to null.

I checked to see this type of behaviour in other standard Acumatica screens but they all manage to reload the data after a browser refresh, without doing anything specific.

Comment: Typically i don't see PXSelectReadOnly used on a view. Usually its PXSelect - not sure if that makes a difference in your case but something to try. Other things to look at would be how your grid is declared on your page sample? do you have any other code in your graph on any of these dacs or views?

Comment: I use PXSelectReadOnly quite liberally and never had a problem with it. When the grid is empty after a refresh, does pressing the 'Cancel' button in the toolbar brings back the data?